Netmiko send_command() not capturing cli timestamp on Juniper devices

Netmiko version = 4.4.0
Python version = 3.11

I'm using Netmiko to log into a Juniper MX router and I want to get the timestamp of the command along with command output.
I log into the Juniper router and send set cli timestamp, then I try running a command but it does not capture the timestamp, it only captures the command output.
I tried using session_log on Netmiko and I'm seeing the Juniper is sending the timestamp output on a separate output first, then the command is run after, not sure why I used an older Netmiko version 2.4.1 and it works for that one, but I need to use the current Netmiko version 4.4.0, not the old version.

Example output below (I know the command is silly, it's just for demonstrating the issue)

Python interpreter session:
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

conn = ConnectHandler(host=host , username=username, password=password, device_type='juniper_junos', conn_timeout=30, session_log='session.log')

conn.send_command('set cli timestamp')

'Nov 13 14:26:24\\nCLI timestamp set to: %b %d %T\\n'

conn.send_command('show version | match model')

'Model: mx480\\n'

Expected vs received output:
Output received:
Model: mx480\\n

Output expected:
TIMESTAMP'Model: mx480\\n'

session.log file:

Last login: Wed Oct 23 01:12:39 2024 from re1
\--- JUNOS 21.2X8.1 Kernel 64-bit  JNPR-12.1-20230321.12d6976_buil
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\> set cli screen-width 511
Screen width set to 511
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\> set cli complete-on-space off
Disabling complete-on-space
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\> set cli screen-length 0
Screen length set to 0
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\> set cli timestamp
Nov 13 14:26:24
CLI timestamp set to: %b %d %T
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
Nov 13 14:26:30
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>
Nov 13 14:26:30
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\> show version | match model
Model: mx480
{master}
REDACTED@re0.NYCMNYZR1CW\>


I was able to find a solution on my own. I compared the Juniper's output in the session_log between netmiko 2.4.1 (which does grab the timestamp on command output after you do 'set cli timestamp') to netmiko 4.4.0 (which was not grabbing the timestamp)
...I found that nemiko 4.4.0 was sending 'set cli complete-on-space off' on initial login. So I made my script do 'set cli complete-on-space' in addition to 'set cli timetamp' , and then netmiko started obtaining the timestamp on command outputs.
I know I'm answering my own question, but hopefully this helps others who might run into this.
